# Homebrew formula - renaming files on install

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

i have the following homebrew formulaL

```
class Software < Formula
    desc "Software"
    homepage "https://blabla"
    version "1.6.0"
  
    if OS.mac? && Hardware::CPU.intel?
      url "https://blabla/releases/download/v1.6.0/software-darwin-10.12-amd64"
      sha256 "ce02a97fb95aca9bba44413d4158f5f2c182f5eb2823bedf1400f556bb9b"
    end
  
    if OS.mac? && Hardware::CPU.arm?
      url "https://blabla/releases/download/v1.6.0/software-darwin-10.12-arm64"
      sha256 "1c69849ba82c10d15706d110ae63bd97c387da2a8cf925653e1bb5c6fc"
    end
  
    if OS.linux? && Hardware::CPU.intel?
      url "https://blabla/releases/download/v1.6.0/software-linux-amd64"
      sha256 "9b7245823a60c85e027929b776753848d4fbdaaa333a49ae171684893"
    end
  
    def install
      bin.install "software*" => "software"
    end
  
    test do
      system "#{bin}/software --version"
    end
  end
```

The problematic part is:

```
    def install
      bin.install "software*" => "software"
    end
```

The files that get downloaded depends on which OS a user is on
before installation. I want to automatically find the downloaded file (whatever the name is), hence why I am trying to use a regex as **bin.install "software*"** with a star to find the downloaded file and install it as **software**

however, I get an error stating **software*** cannot be found

please how would I rectify this issue?

Comment: Assuming it's looking for a regex rather than a glob, you have an invalid regex and probably want `"software.*"` instead. That said, I don't know what bin.install is actually looking for, so YMMV.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs thank you. I will be giving this a try in a few hours.                             . Also bin.install is looking for software-darwin-10.12-amd64  or software-darwin-10.12-arm64 or software-linux-amd64. depending on the operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some Suggestions (But See Caveats Below)

Per the [Homebrew bin.install documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#bininstall-foo), the purpose of `bin.install` is to rename a file within the formula's location within the Cellar, and the key doesn't seem to accept either a glob or a regex. However, since you have the full power of Ruby available to you in addition to the Homebrew formula DSL, you might consider doing something like the following:

```rb
def install
  binfile_with_extension =
    File.basename(Dir.glob "#{prefix}/bin/software*")
  bin.install binfile_with_extension => "software"
end
```

This of course assumes there's only one `software-*` executable. If there's more than one, then you may need to do something to return value of the glob (which should be an Array) to select the correct one for your architecture.

Alternatively, rather than renaming the file itself, you may simply want to symlink it so that you aren't changing something the application might expect. The documentation says that you have full access to both FileUtils and the DSL's [bin.install_symlink](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#file-level-operations) method, so you might consider using some combination of those instead. For example, to create a hardlink in the cellar for your architecture-named file, then symlink it into the correct bin directory using relative symlinks, the following should work:

```rb
def install
  file = Dir.glob("#{prefix}/bin/software*").first
  FileUtils.ln file, "#{prefix}/bin/software"
  bin.install_symlink bin/"software"
end
```

There may be better Homebrew-native options for *renaming* symlinks differently from the file they link to, but I was unable to find one. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist, though.

Additionally, whether or not hardlinking or symlinking is *necessary* in the first place depends on the application. Some applications care about the name they are invoked by (think busybox as an example) while others don't. YMMV.

### Caveats

I'm not currently a Homebrew developer, so there may be other or better ways to do this. Nevertheless, a combination of Ruby globs and the Hombrew DSL features should get you where you want to go.

Please do note that I haven't tested this myself, so the suggestions above may or may not work without tweaking. I offer it simply as a place to start since I don't think `bin.install` is intended to do what you want by itself.

Comment: thank you, I chose the 1st one and made a few tweaks.